# ios: couldn't generate thumbnail, error:Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11832 "Cannot Open"

Tags: ios, flutter

Im using the plugin for creating video thumbnail in both Android and Ios, In Android it works pretty well, but while running same code in IOS i got such error, which i didn't get a solution for this

plugin :- https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail

```
couldn't generate thumbnail, error:Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11832 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media cannot be used., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x280122280 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12431 "(null)"}}
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(IO Error, Failed to write data to file, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:177
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile
package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart:44
<asynchronous suspension>
```